# Illegal use of JSON_CALLBACK in url angular Js

Tags: javascript, angularjs

My goal is to fetch an RSS feed
But always I get this  error

> Error: [$http:badjsonp] Illegal use of JSON_CALLBACK in url

```js
angular.module('djsreaderApp')
  .controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, $http,$sce) {
    var url = "http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select%20*%20from%20xml%20where%20url%3D'http%3A%2F%2Fdailyjs.com%2Fatom.xml'%20and%20itemPath%3D'feed.entry'&format=json&diagnostics=true&callback=JSON_CALLBACK";

    $http.jsonp($sce.trustAsResourceUrl(url)).
      then(function(data, status, headers, config) {
        $scope.feed = {
          title: 'DailyJS',
          items: data.query.results.entry
        };
      });
  });
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to update `$http` call like

```
$http.jsonp(url).then(function(data) {
    console.log(data);
    $scope.feed = {
        title: 'DailyJS',
        items: data.query.results.entry
    };
});
```

Working [**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/gaurav341/u3e8v61d/2/)

Comment: we can no longer use success with $http.jsonp in angular 1.6

Comment: I have updated it for angular upper version using then in `$http.jsonp`

Answer (score 0):

You need to explicitly specify the call back parameter in the `$http` call and remove it from the end of the URL.

```
var url = "http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/...&diagnostics=true";

$http({
  url: $sce.trustAsResourceUrl(url)),
  method: 'jsonp',
  jsonpCallbackParam: 'JSON_CALLBACK'
}).then...
```